# Concatenating xlsx files using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently having a challenge with some data files that I am trying to concatenate. Each of the files has 30 columns but upon merging them, the output was giving me more than 30 columns - (31 to 32) therefore distorting the structure of the data set. Is there a problem wrong with my code?

```py
import pandas as pd

one = pd.read_excel('0403.xlsx')
two = pd.read_excel('0414.xlsx')
three = pd.read_excel('0415.xlsx')
combination = pd.concat([one,three], axis=0)
```

Comment: If the columns in the two dataframes you are concating (e.g. one & three) do not 100% overlap, then new column will be created

Comment: Please include the columns of `one` and `three` in your question, as well as the columns in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hope you are doing well!

Probably columns are not matching in those dataframes, they should be identical otherwise during the `concat` `pandas` will treat them as different and won't do proper concatenation/merge. I would suggest you to do some preprocessing before `concat`, e.g.:

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = [...]  # list of columns that would be set

one = pd.read_excel('0403.xlsx')
one.columns = columns
three = pd.read_excel('0415.xlsx')
three.columns = columns

combination = pd.concat([one,three], axis=0)
```

or you can use the `rename` method to rename only specific columns. To find what columns are different you can do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

one = pd.read_excel('0403.xlsx')
three = pd.read_excel('0415.xlsx')

diff_columns = [col for col in three.columns if col not in one.columns]
```